# T-SQL : find out of sequence values that have occurred before

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This question is to do with finding out of sequence events, but only events that have occurred before. In the following table of data of robot moves, each move should be to the same or higher spot number in sequence, with DIR (Direction) = 1 if this is true. The correct sequence has been preprogrammed (SeqCorr) and the actual sequence recorded (SeqAct) for comparison.

```
Spot Dir SeqCorr SeqAct moveID
------------------------------
 9    1    113    117    1085
 9    1    114    118    1086
 10   1    115    119    1087
 10   1    116    120    1088
 2    0    1      121    1089
 2    1    2      122    1090
 2    1    3      123    1091
 6    1    5      124    1092
 6    1    6      125    1093
 2    0    4      126    1094
 6    1    7      127    1095
 6    1    8      128    1096
```

The question is how would I query the data to detect occurrences  where a Spot's Dir = 0 (like Spot2 with moveID = 1094) and the Spot has been visited at least once before (moveIDs 1089 to 1091).

The output would be a list of moveID and another Status column showing moves that are a return to a previously visited Spot.

```
Status moveID
-------------
 0    1085
 0    1086
 0    1087
 0    1088
 0    1089
 0    1090
 0    1091
 0    1092
 0    1093
 1    1094
 0    1095
 0    1096
```

Comment: How can you tell what's *before* and what's *after*? In a relational database, tables are unordered, so unless you have a column you can use for `order by` like a `create date` or an `identity` column, there is no way of knowing what record is before and what is after. Also, Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: "(like Spot2 with moveID = 1094) and the Spot has been visited at least once before (moveIDs 1089 to 1091)" All the sequences and IDs of the event, that you say have occurred before are larger than the one of the event after. Do you count backwards or what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks Zohar, yes the the moveID acts as an identity column.

Comment: To be clearer about what stick bit is asking, the count of moves increases with time, so the return to spot 2 at moveID 1094 happened after the original 3 visits to spot 2 with moveIDs of 1089 to 1091.

Comment: Presumably Spot 6 is another example, but 9 and 10 are not.  You should explain this difference.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: No Gordon. Spot 6 at moveID 1095 is OK because the Robot is moving from a lower Spot (2) to a higher spot (6), even though 6 has been visited before. The case I am trying to identify is when the Robot moves from a higher Spot to a lower Spot that has been visited before. In the case of the move from Spot 10 to Spot 2 at moveID 1089, the move is OK (status = 0) because 2 has not been visited before. Hope this clarifies :). Your solution looks promising, will be testing in the next 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it is fine for the robot to sit on one spot for adjacent moves.  The issue is later returning to an earlier spot.

If so, this is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  This can be solved with the different of row numbers to get the adjacent moves when the robot is on a given spot:

```
select spot, min(moveid) as min_moveid, max(moveid) as max_moveid
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (order by moveid) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by spot order by moveid) as seqnum_s
      from moves m
     ) m
group by (seqnum - seqnum_s), spot;
```

Why this works is a little hard to explain but quite easy to see.  If you run the subquery, you will see how the difference of row numbers defines each spot.

Now, the question is given the range of moves for each spot -- does a spot appear more than once.  For this, we can now use `count(*)` as a window function.  So, to get the occurrences of duplicates moves:

```
with s as (
      select spot, min(moveid), max(moveid)
      from (select m.*,
                   row_number() over (order by moveid) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by spot order by moveid) as seqnum_s
            from moves m
           ) m
      group by (seqnum - seqnum_s), spot
     )
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             count(*) over (partition by spot) as cnt
      from s
     ) s
where cnt > 1;
```

I believe this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you answer a question? --  Where are min(moveID) and max(moveID) supposed to be used??

Comment: @FyllSee . . . I should have given them aliases, but they show the ranges of moves when a spot is occupied continuously.  This shows one row for a range rather than a separate row for each move.  You can get the original rows using `join`, `exists`, or `in`, but I find this representation often to be more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all moves where a spot has been visited before for a given id

```
select m1.*
from moves m1
join moves m2 ON m1.spot = m2.spot and m1.moveID > m2.moveID
where m2.dir = 0
```

This will give you the moves that occurred in a row

```
select distinct m1.*
from moves m1
join moves m2 ON m1.spot = m2.spot and m1.dir = m2.dir and m1.moveID > m2.moveID
where m1.dir = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final solution to the problem. This time I've added partitions and groupings based the much larger data set that covered Robots on different production lines and in different sections of the manufacturing plant.

```
SELECT line, robot, min(moveid) moveIDmin, max(moveid) moveIDmax
        from (select m.*,
                     row_number() over (partition by line, robot order by moveid) as seqnum,
                     row_number() over (partition by line, robot, spot order by moveid) as seqnum_s
              from #Temp2 m
             ) m
        group by line, robot, (seqnum - seqnum_s), spot
        order by line, robot, moveIDmin
```

The resulting output allows inefficient moves to be easily located like at moveIDmin 298 where the robot has moved back to a spot that was previously visited.

```
   line  robot spot moveIDmin moveIDmax
  AER389X  G    26       1        72
  AER389X  G    30      73       137
  AER389X  J     2     138       139
  AER389X  J     6     140       224
  AER389X  J    10     225       297
  AER389X  J     6     298       301
  AER389X  J    14     302       319
  AER389X  K    14     320       380
  AER389X  K    18     381       468
```